# How to validate the sum of a field of many inlineformset in a CreateView?

Tags: python, django, validation

I have a CreateView of a model with an inlineformset_factory of another model (4 rows, one of each child model). One of the child's model is 'Percentage'. Right now it saves bot the parent and the child model, but I don't have any validation on the *percentage* field, so the User can easily type '11', '34', '02' and '0' and it will save it.

I want to validate that, before saving anything, the sum of the *percentage* fields are 100%. My forms.py look like this:

```
class ParentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ['name', 'observations']


class ChildCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ['percentage', 'material']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ChildCreateForm, self).clean()
        print(cleaned_data['percentage'])


ChildCreateFormCreateFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Parent, Child, form=ChildCreateForm, extra=4)
```

So far so good, I can validate every percentage row individually, but I want to validate the total sum.

Should I validate the form with Javascript? There is a way with Django? Or it is best a third option?

Comment: You need to do validate on the server. It might be useful to have JavaScript validation as well, but you can't rely on it because the user could disable it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can subclass `BaseInlineFormSet` and override the `clean` method. instance with a clean method.

```
from django.forms import BaseInlineFormSet

class BaseChildFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        total_percentage = sum(f.cleaned_data['percentage'] for f in self.forms)
        if total_percentage != 100:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Total percentage must be 100")
```

Then use your class when you create the formset class.

```
ChildCreateFormCreateFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Parent, Child, form=ChildCreateForm, formset= BaseChildFormSet, extra=4)
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-methods-on-an-inlineformset) for more info.

Comment: Is there a way to carry out validation of a field's values between two consecutive (inline formset) rows by **iterating** over the rows? **For example**, if I have a field `price`, I want to check if the `price` fields' values (between two consecutive rows) do not swing by more than 10%.